# C*-algebra of a singular surface foliation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, foliations

Noncommutative geometry associates a $C^*$-algebra $C^*(S,{\cal F})$ with a foliation $\cal F$ on a manifold $S.$

1. Did somebody study this construction for noncompact surfaces $S$?
2. What I am really interested in is an extension of the above construction to surface $S$ foliations admitting some singularities (like $k$-pronged singularities in Thurston's theory of measured surface foliations). Is there a version of $C^*(S,{\cal F})$ for such foliations more reasonable than that for $S$ with singularities of $\cal F$ removed?